# Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir

Tags: reactjs, linux, react-native, ubuntu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW3Jq.png)

I'm unable to solve this problem can some one help me

I'am unable to solve this problem in Ubuntu

=>list of error that I have faced

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/home/hassnain/Desktop/native_app/practice_app/android/local.properties'.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/home/hassnain/Desktop/native_app/practice_app/android/local.properties'.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org